# Looking for a folder comparison utility for unit/integration tests

Tags: windows, unit-testing, filesystems, integration-testing

Context:
Environment: MS Windows 7 or 2008.
Code: .NET (C#)

I wrote some code that changes the file system: copies files, delete them, creates folders etc.

I'd like to have some integration tests for this code: I want to execute the code on a given folder, and then compare the result with a predefined expected folder.
All I need is a folder comparison tool which would compare the folder structure, **based on names only** (other parameters, such as creation date, size, permissions - are irrelevant).
Most importantly, it should be easily automated in code (.NET) or as a command line utility with a readable output.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple PowerShell script using the [Compare-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347568.aspx) cmdlet for that:

```
$expected = Get-ChildItem C:\ExpectedDirTree
$actual = Get-ChildItem C:\ActualDirTree

Compare-Object $expected $actual -Property Name
```

This script will compare two directory structures based on the `Name` property of their nodes, which can be either [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2fzb02.aspx) or [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) objects. The result is an *array of objects* that represent the *differences* between the two structure in a format that is fairly easy to parse:

```
Name                SideIndicator
-----------         -------------
SomeDirectory            =>
SomeFile                 <=
```

The objects in the resulting array have two properties, which you can use to determine the outcome of the test:

- `Name`: the name of the directory or file that exists in one structure and not the other
- `SiteIndicator`: a string that represents whether the object exists in the structure on the *left side* of the comparison or in the one on the *right side*

Answer (score 0):

I gave it another thought, and found out that listing all files with their relative path, sorted by path and name, is sufficient: if the actual file list is equal to the expected file list, then the test passes. Otherwise, it fails.

Listing the files can be done by:

- Windows command line `dir` command, but it lacks the feature of relative path.
- Code (which should be tested, too)
- An external program, such as [Swiss File Knife](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/), like so:
  `list -sort -relnames c:\my\path\ +tofile c:\output\my_list.txt`
  (which eventually was my choice)